# OneDrive on Nokia Lumia 928 windows phone still showing deleted pictures

Tags: onedrive, pictures

I have some pictures that I want deleted from my windows phone, and i deleted them from my regular camera roll, but they are still showing up in my onedrive folder, even though those as well have been deleted from onedrive via online. Is there anyway to wipe that folder on my phone, or delete the onedrive folder? once that is gone, these pictures will be gone as well.

Answer (score -2):

Look at the Paper Bin in onedrive.live.com, your unwanted photos are still there. Simply empty the trash.